# Read Only Filesystem for Kiosk Application

Tags: 18.04, read-only, kiosk, embedded-system

I have something like an Intel NUC running Ubuntu that operates like a touchscreen kiosk in an industrial environment.  It gets power cycled regularly and I want to protect against hard drive corruption.  How do I make the filesystem read only, but still allow Chrome to operate normaly, other code to run (C++, Python), and MySQL database writes?  How would I allow for alterations of `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`?

Answer (score 1):

This https://wiki.debian.org/ReadonlyRoot might be what you're looking for.  You can mount parts of the filesystem as read-only, but leave things like /etc or /var available to be written to as needed (technically /var and /etc must be writeable).

I'm going to assume this device is using emmc, flash or a DOM type block device.  If that's the case, there are other/additional methods you can use to reduce block device activity and potentially help prevent corruption on power-loss.
https://mcuoneclipse.com/2019/04/01/log2ram-extending-sd-card-lifetime-for-raspberry-pi-lorawan-gateway/ explains one method.